# emacsw32 - keybindings - no meta - clojure box

Tags: clojure, key-bindings, emacsw32

I have installed clojure-box on my Windows 7 laptop, this by default installs emacsW32. I understand that this version remaps slightly the standard Emacs keybindings to be more windows friendly, however I cannot find my META key.

Usually META is ALT, but I cannot locate it on this install, would it be possible to define META M-x as ALT GR or the apps key? Or is there a way to find out where my META key is by default?

[Clojure Box](http://clojure.bighugh.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default clojure box does have alt mapped to META, atleast that's how it was for me.

Go to the scratch buffer and type

w32-alt-is-meta

and then place your cursor at the end of the line and press C-x C-e
If the mini buffer shows nil , that means alt is not the meta key. It shows "t" in my emacs.

Check out http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Keyboard.html

OTOH, if you already have an emacs version installed other than the one that came with clojure box, you just can install slime on that one and play with clojure. Slime can be installed stand alone or from ELPA.

Update: 
Answer that worked: 
Type the following in scratch buffer and eval it using C-x C-e to make alt the meta key again.

(setq w32-alt-is-meta \t)

Comment: Thanks yes it did return nil. I tried to set the apps key to be my meta key but emacs returns a lisp error. When I use the command. (w32-apps-modifier [meta])